# Axios not sending custom header during options request

Tags: vue.js, axios, apigee

I have a running Vue.js application that request to the server.
My client-side application is running on e.g. `cms.abc.com` and the server in ApiGee running on this dns `server.abc.com`

The request code using axios is

```
const headers = {
  'x-api-key': 'xxxxx123123'
}

return axios({
  method: get,
  url: 'server.abc.com/items',
  headers: headers
}).then(response => {
  console.log(respnose.data)
})
```

When I check the browser network I'm getting status `401 Unauthorized` during `OPTIONS` request.
The APIgee CORS has been enabled, but when I check the logs from the ApiGee the value for `x-api-key` is missing.

I'm also not sure why my client side application is still sending OPTIONS request. I'm expecting that it should skip the CORS since the client and the server are having the same origin. which is `abc.com`

Comment: cms.abc.com and server.abc.com is not same origin, as you can read here: https://www.acunetix.com/blog/web-security-zone/what-is-same-origin-policy/ under "What Is the Origin
" title

Comment: Ok @BallonUra but any idea why the client side is not sending the header during OPTIONS?

Comment: Check the network tab on your browser for the OPTIONS request, did you see the 'x-api-key' header on the request? You can also try another HTTP client like Postman, to see if the problem is on the Axios config or at ApiGee

Comment: I can see OPTIONS request but there's no x-api-key being passed. Postman is different behaviour it's not a browser so it will pass the x-api-key during options. I'm wondering why my custom header not being passed during OPTIONS my client side app